# Google Data Studio connect to cloud datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

Is it possible to connect the cloud datastore to data studio? I just can find the Cloud SQL and BigQuery connector only.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible directly.
But the quickest workaround is to use this feature https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-cloud-datastore where you can load your Datastore backup into BigQuery, and then connect that BigQuery dataset to Data Studio.